# Change android studio build output window text to english

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Chinese operating system, when compile an Android project, the error displayed in Chinese, as shown below.

[image]

How to change the text to English, so I can google it conveniently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the android studio, double `shift-click`, then enter `edit custom vm options`...
[image: edit custom vm options]

Add one line:

-Duser.language=en

Restart android studio. Your error message will be English.

Comment: You find this in the menu "Help/Find Action..." and it worked perfectly for me. AS 2021.3.1 here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Data translation is not available in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution may be , you can copy the Chinese text and translate that to english simply by using "chinese to English" translation option available in online and then you can search for the erros .

[Link:](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chinese+to+english&oq=chinese+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39j0j5.2555j1j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)